# WinEdtPDF giving invalid floating point exception after reboot (PC, Win 10/11, WinEdt 11.1)

Tags: viewers, winedt

I have been using the WinEdtPDF viewer with WinEdt V11.1 without issues. However, immediately after a reboot it now reports:

```
            Exception ElnvalidOp in module WinEdtPDF.exe at
            0000000000436509.
            Invalid floating point operation.
```

whenever I attempt to open it.  The problem occurs irrespective of how I attempt to open it, i.e. whether opening from within WinEdt, from the file manager, or from a command line (with admin priviledges).  This same problem occurs on 2 different devices, one running Win 10 and the other Win 11.  Both devices have had recent updates to their OS (which is potentially the cause of the issue).

Is anyone else having this problem? Does anyone know a solution, or have a suggestion to try?
Thanks.

PS. I have reinstalled WinEdt v11.1 (which includes WinEdtPDF) and the problem remains.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome. // What‘s the LaTeX related problem? Did you post it in the wrong place?

Comment: It's not directly a latex problem, but rather with packages associated with working with latex.  I have seen other problems related to WinEdt posted here.  But I'll move it to StackExchange instead.  I'm not sure which is forum is best.

Comment: OK.  The WinEdt Team provided the answer.  I'll post it here for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be caused by Windows corrupting the file WinEdtPDF.dat when it forces a close of WinEdtPDF before restarting. The corrupted file needs to be deleted and a fresh copy generated.

In **WinEdt** navigate as follows:
Options / Configuration Wizard / Browse Local Folder
This will open File Explorer. Open the PDF subfolder. Delete the file WinEdtPDF.dat.

Restart WinEdtPDF and a new WinEdtPDF.dat file will be generated automatically. All settings and recent file history will be lost, unfortunately.

Thanks to the WinEdt Team for the solution.